# IIS Returns a /IISConfig/Config.aspx (Blank) Page

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8, sensenet

I'm trying to install Sense/NET on my Computer for demo purposes. I managed to install the Demo (Community Edition) Version on Port 80 as i followed the instructions on their [WIKI Page](http://wiki.sensenet.com/How_to_install_Sense/Net_from_web_deployment_package_(IIS_7.5_and_IIS_7.0))

but when i tried to install another copy of Sense/NET (regardless of being a Demo/Community/Evaluation Edition) i kept getting this Blank /IISConfig/Config.aspx Page.

I am running on Windows 8.1 and IIS 8.x

if i am mistaken in any configurations please let me know and help me.

[image: The Blank /IISConfig/Config.aspx Page]

Comment: As you've said you are using port 80, why you use localhost:85 instead of localhost:80

Comment: because port 80 has the initial installation of my Sense/NET. i am trying to install a new/copy of Sense/NET on a different port. just to see differences

Comment: Port number in this case is a very important as far as i know, Please check make sure the port you want to use is not yet taken by your machine. I am aware using port like this 80 coz every machine mostly port 80 is used that's why we need to configure the port always as possible to avoid port conflict.

Comment: For additional info.. use tool curports if im not mistaken,it will help you to find which port is running on your machine.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

EDIT: According to their [WIKI](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Getting_started_-_installation_and_maintenance) (again)

> First of all, check the port number: it should be set to '80'.

it is just strange as it seem that it must be under Port 80 and Port 80 only. is there any walk-through such limitations ?. like for example, another web app is also running along Port 80 and Port 80 alone ?. can this be achievable via web.config or iis ?

if not, there technically there is nothing we can do. The least is to mark my own post as the answer.

Answer (score 6):

For SenseNet to work properly you have to register the url in two places:

- in IIS Manager, on the IIS site you created
- In SenseNet Content Explorer (the admin GUI), on the site content's Edit page.

So it is absolutely OK to have any number of urls with different port numbers, the localhost:80 above is just an example in the wiki.

[How to change url and authentication settings](http://wiki.sensenet.com/How_to_change_url_and_authentication_settings)

Answer (score 2):

As Miklós've written Port 80 is only an example, there is no limitations on port numbers. You can configure any other port you like as long the IIS setting is corresponds the SenseNet site content's "URL list" configurations.

I assume default install goes with port 80, so if you've installed an other copy of SenseNet you should edit manually the second portal's ports in the IIS and in SN too. You can either edit the latter through the Edit page "URL List" field of the site content (eg. /Root/Sites/Default_Site) in SenseNet Content Explorer or set it in the web configuration file's "urllist" section.

Answer (score 0):

Try to user your port using like this:

```
localhost:80 or any port you configured
```

Hope it help